# How to override default behavior in Json.Net JsonConverter

Tags: serialization, proxy, json.net

I wish to peel off a proxy object before serialization, and figured I could do that in `JsonConverter.ReadJson()`.

However since the `JsonConverter.ReadJson()` is abstract, there is no default behavior to call after I strip off the proxy.

Is there such a thing as a DefaultJsonConverter I should derive from instead?

Comment: Do you know the target type ahead of time or no?  Or I should say, maybe you could give us a JSON example? I'm not sure I understand, but I think I have a basic idea.  Normally for something like this you call methods on the `serializer` parameter (ie. `serializer.Populate` to populate the object you instantiate)